# Any better way to do this in c++, calculating a solution to puzzle (49! outcomes, 49 loops)

Tags: c++

Basically there are 49 tiles in this puzzle. They each have 4 colours on each edge. I need to create a 7x7 puzzle where each edge of one tile matches the colour of the edges of the tiles adjacent to them, for example a 2x2 solution:

```
       blue             purple
yellow     green  green       pink
       pink              blue

       pink              blue
purple     yellow yellow     green
       blue              pink
```

I was going to assign numbers to each colour, then do something like (psuedocode):

```
for i in 1 to 49
    for j in 1 to 48
       if left colour of j == right colour of i
           join them
       for k in 1 to 47
           if left colour of k == right colour of j
.....
......
```

if all 49 have been assigned end

I don't even know if this many iterations is possible, any suggestions? Thanks.

Sample image of 4 squares (real puzzle is 49 squares) https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ISpQ.png

**ONLY READ IF YOU REALLY WANT THE ACTUAL PUZZLE:**

The actual puzzle is called "the magic square tile puzzle"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0MBl.jpg

I was going to assign a decimal for each half of a beetle such that when added together they == 1. Then I would iterate like above and check if when added they == 1.

Comment: Can you post the exact wording of this problem? It's hard to understand it with the way you've phrased it.

Comment: The puzzle is 49 squares and you have to arrange them in a 7x7 big square such that the edges match (each 1 small square has 4 colours on each edge, so the purple side of 1 square has to be next to the purple side of another square)

Comment: I'd say that the problem with your current approach is that you don't account for the top and bottom edges. Simply looking at the left and right edges does not guarantee that two tiles should be joined. May I ask where you found this problem?

Comment: *I don't even know if this many iterations is possible*  Of course it's possible.  Mind you, at `10^9` iterations a second it's still going to take about `2*10^46` years.

Comment: That was just a simplified idea, I would account for top and bottom edges but I'm just wondering if this is even possible since it's so many iterations and has to go through maybe 35! outcomes until it finds a solution that works. The problem is a little more confusing than the example I gave but I'm just asking for a general idea then I can solve these little things

Comment: I edited in the actual puzzle for those who asked

Comment: I'm wondering if it is possible to subdivide the problem into smaller sets, first solve a 4x4 portion, then treat those as a new block. Then do a 4x4 of the new block and so on until it is solved....

Comment: Are you given arbitrary tiles? Can you expect to be given a set of 49 tiles that will not have a solution? Are you trying to check to see if a given set of exactly 49 tiles has ANY solution or do you want to find them all?

Comment: @fightermagethief There is guaranteed at least 1 solution, I just want ANY ONE solution

Comment: @RedX Certainly could find a faster solution, but if the solution doesn't work then you have to break down the blocks and try a different configuration. Seems like the worst case scenario would be iterating over all possibilities still... I may not be thinking about it right though.

Comment: What about counting the number of each color edges? You know that if you have only 2 green edges, then they either are next to each other somewhere or on the outside edges.

Comment: @fightermagethief there are 49 squares, and only like 5 or 6 colours, so there is definitely more than 2 of each edge if you get what I mean

Comment: @highperformancemark: it seems to me it's stretching "of course" a bit when you're talking about more time than the universe has existed, and almost certainly more energy than the big bang.

Comment: Yes of course, that was a contrived example. Let's say you had 7 of one color, then you know that 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 of those will be on the outside edge. It is a way to simplify the problem.

Comment: @fightermagethief That's a good idea, but I still think the general backbone of the method by iterating through 49 loops is too much, surely there's a better way

Comment: Yeah and that's 49 factorial which is 6.0828186e+62

Comment: What RedX said is interesting. It reminded me of something I had to go look up again. It is geometric magic shape puzzles where a "target shape" can be created. The target shape though is a direct reduction of the overall shape. I am not sure if this problem is reducible in the same way...

Comment: Ah, yeah I had to look around, but yeah. If you can make the same configuration with the given tiles into "sub-puzzles", then it is solvable through an iterative process (feasible). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_magic_square

Comment: I'm sitting here trying to figure out how it's possible for humans to complete, but we seem to think it's time-consumingly impossible for humans. I'm starting to think of how a human would do it and translate it to computer form. Let's assume (and hope) there are many solutions. A human would start with one, and keep adding on. If they got to a dead end they would retract the previous one and use a different square with the same coloured edge. Then try again, if they try all remaining squares without success they'd remove the square before that then try all remaining squares again, ideas?

Comment: Why do you think there is a substantially faster way to solve this?  I could believe it coukd go either way, superficially.  Is this an assignment, or something you thought up?

Comment: I guess an analog of that would be "what does a purely iterative approach do that a human would not do." Like the iterative process could start by trying a solution where the first tiles did not match edges at all. Something a human wouldn't do. The process of making sub-blocks seems to only apply to the construction and not the solving of such puzzles as well...Will have to think on this...

Comment: [Constraint_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) and [stochastic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization) may help.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need is [Depth-first search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

The color of each tile could be represented by an `enum`:

```
enum class TileColor {
    Blue,
    Purple,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    // ...
};
```

Then you could represent each tile with a class:

```
struct Tile {
    TileColor up;
    TileColor down;
    TileColor left;
    TileColor right;
};
```

Then in the main process, you could initialize a 7*7 puzzle board like:

```
int main() {
    // To define a 7*7 board, vector is recommended.
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile> > board(7, std::vector<Tile>(7));

    // You can loop the vector in a traditional way like:
    for (auto row = 0; row < board.size(); ++row) {
        for (auto col = 0; col < board[row].size(); ++col) {
            // Some code here.

            // To assign a value to a tile, the code looks like:
            // board[row][col].left = TileColor::Blue;

            // To test color is match, the code looks like:
            // if (board[row][col].right == (board[row][col + 1].left) { ... }
            // The boundary condition is also needed to be considered here.
        }
    }

    // To loop in a more "C++" way, you could use iterator:
    for (auto row = board.begin(); row != board.end(); ++row) {
        for (auto col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) {
            // Some code here.

            // To assign a value to a tile, the code looks like:
            // col->left = TileColor::Blue;

            // To test color is match, the code looks like:
            // if (col->right == (col + 1)->left) { ... }
            // The boundary condition is also needed to be considered here.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, above is just a simple explanation about the basic data types of the problem, for the algorithm to solve the problem, DFS will be a proper one. More specifically, you may want to use a `vector<Tile> tiles(7*7);` to store all your tiles reading from an input file or console, then in the loop, you try to pick up a tile from the `tiles` and put it on the `board`, then check if it matched with others. If matched, the loop continues to pick up the next tile. If not matched, you goes back to the states before by taking the tile from the board and put it back in `tiles`. If all your tiles are put on the board, then a solution come out.

One more hint is that you may want to use a `9*9` board for a problem of `7*7` where two more rows and columns are added for you like a boarder to the board.

Comment: i prefer the syntax `for (auto& row : board) for (auto& col : row)`

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Yes, I agreed. I just forgot that one :-P